# customizing error pages in Ping Federate 6.10

Tags: pingfederate

Any one know about how to change default error pages in PingFederate 6.10 during sso login. for example, in PF after no of unsuccessfull attempts exceeded user face error page from PF.
my question is how to change default ping federate sso user facing pages to refer external web pages? (i noticed too many inbuilt error pages are in Ping Federate)

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: This question is very ambiguous - not explaining what it is, nor why, the user is trying to achieve what is queried.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PF 6.10 Admin Guide to start -

https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/Customizing+User-Facing+Screens#CustomizingUser-FacingScreens-1163105

You can modify these to add redirects to your own pages or customize these for your own message/look & feel.

If you have more questions on this, please post a new question.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I posted a new one related to this.