# customizing error pages in PF 6.10

Tags: pingfederate

From my understanding from InErrorResource parameter we can specify the error page URL but the case is we are having multiple error pages. for example number of trails exceeded we are displaying login attempts exceeded and for no default URL and no targetresource we are displaying end application not available like.

Customizing the in-built error pages in Ping federate is one way. any other solutions?

Edited :
First i explain what i am looking for, after 3 unsuccessful attempts user have to redirected to our application error page not the one from PingFederate and when user hitting invalid target resource or without target resource we found error message like "Single Sign-on - No Target" in this case also we need to redirect the user to our application error page saying hey you hit the invalid URL". Please note we are having two different error pages for above scenario's.

Question:
1. Editing the respective error pages in Ping Federate is one way to solve but we need to use our application error pages. 
2. another approach is appending InErrorResource parameter in the URL, in this approach how can we specify our application to display login attempts exceeded page or invalid target URL page?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: In your question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692079/customizing-error-pages-in-ping-federate-6-10 you were complaining about too many error pages. Now, you're wanting to create new ones for all the different errors. I'm not quite sure what it is that you want to do... So. Please clarify: It is understood that you are at baseline install... But what exactly are you trying to achieve, AND WHY? Once that's understood, then we can try to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Andrew K. Thanks for reply. Please look on the edited section. I'm new to Ping Federate, so if any thing i misunderstood or asked mistaken please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your application's pages by specifying the InErrorResource URL, but no information is provided to the URL for it to show error-specific information.

About the only thing that I can suggest to you is to modify the error pages by capturing information in a variable of some sort and redirect to your application pages. Or just use the pages with modifications to look like your application.

It's interesting to note that what you're asking for was standard back in 4.X days, prior to when we added the error templates. We have a feature request listed currently (PPQ-792) for bringing this functionality back into the product. If you open a support case, you can be added to the list of requesting customers.